# Pentaho spoon search and replace especial character in rows

Tags: data-cleaning, data-warehouse, pentaho-data-integration, stage, spoon

I have a csv file with mime type US-ASCII and one column in the dataset look like this:

| id | V_name |
| --- | --- |
| 210001 | cha?ne des Puys |
| 210030 | M?los |
| 213004 | G?ll? |
| 213021 | S?phan |
| 221110 | Afd?ra |

And so on.

I would like to change those characters to:

| id | V_name |
| --- | --- |
| 210001 | chaine des Puys |
| 210030 | Milos |
| 213004 | Gollu |
| 213021 | Suphan |
| 221110 | Afdera |

The thing is that there are 95 rows of this kind, how can I search and replace those rows?
I using the suite PDI spoon.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why in some cases `?` is replaced with `i` and another with `o` or `e`?

Comment: The csv file is just like that from this website https://data.humdata.org/m/dataset/volcano-population-exposure-index-gvm

Comment: these files appear already corrupted, and there is no way to 100% accurately restore them to original values, you can try to contact owners of the data, or just find another data source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Iłya Bursov has stated, the source file you are reading doesn't provide the correct characters, it is providing the ? in the source, so if you want to correct it, you'll have to do it manually.

I don't think it is worth it, unless you know you are going to get always the same set of V_name over time and different files. In that case you could create a file to correlate the **V_name** in your source with the ? characters to a **V_name_corrected** with the correct display for the characters. This seems to be an exercise, so I would let the names as they are. In real life, I would contact the provider of the file with the incorrect character set to tell them that they need to correct the generation of the file to provide the correct characters in the file.